# Is it possible to make Traversal an instance of IsString

Tags: haskell, types, haskell-lens, aeson

I want to use string literal as Traversal, but I am a bit lost in types.
Is it possible to create this instance?

```
import Control.Lens
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.Lens
import Data.String
import Data.Default

{- Having:
key'  :: AsValue t => Text -> Traversal' t (Maybe Value)
_JSON :: (ToJSON a, FromJSON a) => Traversal' t a
-}

instance (AsValue t, FromJSON v, ToJSON v, Default v) => IsString (Traversal' t v) where
  fromString k = key' (fromString k) . non (toJSON def) . _JSON
```

To achieve something like this inside State monad:

```
"some-key" .= (3 :: Int)
```

Problem with universally quantified type instances. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't get your code to compile, but that shouldn't matter. I assume that you have a function of type

```
fromStringTraversal :: (AsValue t, FromJSON v, ToJSON v, Default v) 
                    => String -> Traversal' t v 
fromStringTraversal = undefined
```

Then to write your instance, simply inline the definition of `Traversal'` into the instance head. This works because any type variables in an instance are universally quantified over implicitly anyways.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, FlexibleInstances, GADTs #-}

instance (a ~ a', b ~ b', AsValue b, Default a, FromJSON a, ToJSON a, Applicative f) 
       => IsString ((a -> f a') -> b -> f b') where
  fromString = fromStringTraversal
```

The `a ~ a', b ~ b'` constraints could be moved from the context to the instance head, but this way gives better type inference. Then

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

-- Infered type:
-- test :: (AsValue s, MonadState s m) => m ()
test = "some-key" .= (3 :: Int)
```

Comment: This example also requires `RankNTypes` to talk about the lens type synonyms, `FlexibleInstances` for the `IsString` instance, either `TypeFamilies` or `GADTs` for `~`, and `hiding ((.=))` when importing `Data.Aeson`.